# How to transform and project array elements from http backend in angular7

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

From the http backend I get an observable with a list of users:

```
Observable<User[]>
```

User is defined as:

```
export interface User {
  id:number;
  username:string;
}
```

I am using angular 7.
In the end as the result of the backend call I want to have an **array of the user ids**?

What is the best and RXJS-like way to perform this transition?

Comment: Using the [`map` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html)

Comment: please share your service or the code you are invoking http request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your service:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
class MyService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://my-api.com/users')
  }
}
```

**In your component:**

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({ /* ... * / })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  userIds$: Observable<number[]>;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userIds$ = this.myService.getUsers().pipe(
      map(users => users.map(user => user.id))
    )

    // Now whether you directly subscribe to `this.userIds$` or use the `async` pipe.
    // The Result will be an array of numbers (user ids)
  }
}
```

> Learn More about [Array `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [RxJS `map` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html). You will use these *a lot*.

Answer (score 1):

Using your defined interface and that the http call returns an array that conforms to that interface you would do it like this. The conversion between the returned type to the expected type (User interface to number in this case) can be done with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

**userService.ts**

```
export class UserService {
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers() : Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>('/some/url');
  }
}
```

**userComponent.ts**

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  userIds: number[];
  constructor(private readonly service: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUsers().subscribe(users => this.userIds = users.map(_ => _.id));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making it super verbose :)

```
this.userIds = []
observable.subscribe(users => {
 this.userIds = users.map(user => user.id)
})
```

- Subscribe to the 'result' of the API call
- observable will present you with array of Users
- Map function applies function to each element of array and returns, in this case, the user.id
- Assign this result to our userIds array

Answer (score 0):

you can use .map() function to achieve this.
Below is the example of how you can do this:

```
var userIds= Users.map(function(user) {
  return user.id
});
```